# Pythonic way to define function closures

Tags: python, function, coding-style, closures, metaprogramming

I have some function defined in a module `mymodule`:

```
def f1(a, b):
    # do something with a and b
```

For a number of design reasons, in the main script I need to call `f1` from a higher-order function `mycaller`, which will only pass `a` as an argument. The other parameter `b` is only available in the main script.

Internally, `mycaller` looks as follows:

```
  def mycaller(list_of_functions, a):
        for f in list_of_functions:
             f(a)
```

So far, I have done

```
from mymodule import f1

bb = myB()
aa = myA()

def closure_f1(a):
    return f1(a, bb)

mycaller([closure_f1], aa)
```

Is this the correct way of designing such a closure?
Right now I end up with many closures in main script which looks ugly and I believe might also give problems with serialization.
How can I improve this?

Here are some attempts that I made without a separate `closure_f1` function:

```
mycaller([f1],a)
```

However, then the function misses the b argument.
Then I have tried

```
mycaller([f1(b)],a)
```

but of course this lead to a function call (which fails) rather than in passing the function with argument `b` set.

Comment: "clouser_f1" should be "mycaller"? Also, last two lines in first code block look out of place. I'm also not sure what the question is. If you want to have a method that calls `f1` with one argument fixed, ok, then call it with one argument fixed. Your code looks alright, what's the problem?

Comment: I dont think what you're showing is a closure. There are no free variables, you are simply using a global variable

Comment: @Andre Tyukin: I have updated my question

Comment: sorry still udpating

Comment: Let me know if it makes sense, I would consider starting a new clearer question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several possibilities:

**1. Use `functools.partial`**

If you want to fix the first argument (or first few arguments), just use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
mycaller([partial(f1, bb)], aa)
```

For this to work with your example you would have to swap the order of arguments `a` and `b` in the definition of `f1`.

---

**2. Define your own `partial` that fixes the second argument**

If you want to fix the second argument, the `functools.partial` doesn't help, because it works from left to right. But if you have a lot of functions where you have to fix the second argument, you could do something like this:

```
def partial2(f, y):
  def res(x):
    return f(x, y)
  return res
```

and then use it as follows:

```
mycaller([partial2(f1, bb)], aa)
```

**3. Just use `lambda`s:**

This is a somewhat verbose, but at the same time the most flexible possibility:

```
mycaller([lambda x: f1(x, bb)], aa)
```

An explicit lambda could be preferable if you don't want to pollute the namespace by a bunch of trivial function definitions.

**4. Just define a helper function**

I don't see anything catastrophic in defining a helper function, especially if it is used often. So, just leave `closure_f1` as-is and use:

```
mycaller([closure_f1], aa)
```

Comment: answer is yours...would you just suggest an improved title for the question?in the comment, they told me these are not really closures. I would like people to find your answer in the future